# Trouble with removing table rows added with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm a jQuery newbie, and I have trouble with a little script I created.

First of all, I have a table with 5 default rows. These are sortable, using a plugin called "Table Drag'n'Drop". A column in that table consists of a linked X which removes the table row when clicked.

The table looks like this:

```
<table id="tracks">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>File</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="track">
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
      <td><input type="file" /></td>
      <td><a href="#" class="deleteme">X</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The `tr.track` repeats itself five times in the code. These are perfectly draggable and removable by clicking the X.

This is the jQuery code:

```
// makes the table sortable
$("#tracks").tableDnD();

// adds more rows (just a link)
$("#addRow").click(function() {
    newTrack = 'same code as tr.track'
    $("tbody").append(newTrack);
    return false;
});

// delete rows
$("a.deleteme").click(function() {
    $(this).parents("tr.track").fadeOut("fast", function() {
        $(this).remove();
        return false;
    });
});
```

When I add a new table row, this row won't let it sort or be removed by clicking the X. Seems like the jQuery doesn't notices it's there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use [`live`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live#typefn):

> Binds a handler to an event (like click) for all current - and future - matched element.

Sounds like a winner. So just replace this line:

```
$("a.deleteme").click(function() {
```

With this, using `live` instead:

```
$("a.deleteme").live('click', function() {
```

#### Edit:

As far as the sorting, apparently the plugin you are using is not taking advantange of `live` internally. The only solution is then to call the init code again after you add a new table row. You can do this fine with some plugins and some others don't handle it nicely. Let us know how it goes. Just add this:

```
$("#tracks").tableDnD();
```

Inside the `#addMore` click handler, after you append `newTrack`.

Comment: I took too long finding the link to live you beat me to it.

Comment: Thanks, that made it work! The only thing is that the row isn't sortable anymore.

Comment: The DnD plugin must not use live internally. You need to call $("#tracks").tableDnD(); again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) to bind current and future elements to events.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, you guys are fast!

Answer (score 1):

You have to refresh the Sortable in JQuery.

$("#tracks").sortable("refresh");

This is assuming that you are using out of the box Sortable plugin. .tableDnD looks like an custom extension method.

Answer (score 1):

The tableDnD plugin has a method which has probably been added since this question was originally posted but for the same of completeness I'll add it here:

```
.tableDnDUpdate()
```

As the tableDnD documentation states,

> cause the table to update its rows so the drag and drop functionality works if, for example, you’ve added a row.